# getting Xcode for Mac version 10.15.7

Tags: xcode, macos, macos-catalina

My computer is running macOS Catalina. I have Xcode installed but I cannot open it. I keep getting an error that maybe my OS version cannot run the installed XCode version. There is no update for my computer OS -- Catelina seems to be the latest it's eligible for. How do I get a working version of Xcode?

The error says something about Xcode cannot be installed on Mac HD and that version 11.3 or later required. But I'm betting there has to be an Xcode version for Mac 10.15.7 that I can use. But I cannot figure how to install that.

Comment: You are correct that some computers can't go beyond Catalina. Just go to developer.apple.com, sign in, go to the downloads section. You can get any version of Xcode you want.

Answer (score 13):

Yes, as @matt said. MacOS 10.15.7 requires Xcode 12.4, you can find that here: https://developer.apple.com/download/all/?q=Xcode%2012.4

Answer (score 2):

A little extra guidance for Windows users a little lost in finding the right download:

After you have signed in or created an account at `developer.apple.com` one way to find the download is shown below:

**(1) Click on search icon and search for "Xcode support" then in the results click "Xcode - Support"**

[image]

**(2) In the second section of that page click on "Downloads Page"**

[image]

**(3) Finally, search "Xcode 12.4" and you should be able to down the `.xip` file from the top result**

[image]

Note that this download can take a while (just over an hour for me).